# div dynamically between footer and header

Tags: html, css

I want to add a div for my content between a **fixed** footer and header.

The height of the header and footer may change. So I don't want any paddings or margins that refer to the height of the footer or header.

In other words: I want to be able to change the size of the footer or header in a single place without usage of css preprocessors .

I have seen many examples but they all used **hardcoded references to the height of the header or footer. I don't want these**.

Is this possible at all? If so I would like to know.

Here a example of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a flexbox grid for the header & footer, they will expand and contract as they need but you won't have to hardcode heights.

Comment: **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!